# How do I download images from Picasa Web API in Java

Tags: java, api, download, picasa

Google's developer guide explains how to [upload photos](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#UploadPhotos) to the Picasa Web Albums, but how do I download the image file in Java so that I can save it on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have any familiarity with the Picasa Web Albums API, but this is what I think may work by just looking at the Javadocs:

```
// read all photos from an album
URL feedUrl = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/username/albumid/albumid";

AlbumFeed feed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, AlbumFeed.class);

for(PhotoEntry photo : feed.getPhotoEntries()) {
    MediaSource mediaSource = photo.getMediaSource();
    InputStream photoInputStream = mediaSource.getInputStream();
    // read from the photoInputStream here to get contents of photo
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the self-comment, but you can use the MediaSource.getContentType() method to figure out what type of file you have.